# Convert rend iterator to end iteterator

Tags: c++

*This is not a duplicate of how to convert a `reverse_iterator` to an `iterator` because I want the result to be different to the normal conversion.*

Given only a `reverse_iterator` that is returned from `rend`, is it possible to convert this to the corresponding `iterator` that would be returned from `end`?

For example

```
std::vector<int> myvec = {...};
auto rit = myvec.rend();
auto it = MAGIC(rit);
it == myvec.end(); // true
```

If it is not possible to do this given only the `reverse_iterator`, what is the minimum information needed to do this? (So I can consider workarounds).

Comment: I think the minimum information to do this besides the `rend` iterator  would be the distance from begin to end. i.e. the size of the container.

Comment: There is no relationship between `rend()` and `end()`. Minimal information needed to reconstruct `end()` is `end()`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Short answer: No.**
An iterator refers to one single point in a container, wihtout actual knowledge of the container itself. The iterators returned by `end()` and `rend()` point to different ends of a container, i.e. there might be some, many or no elements between the points they refer to, regardless of the reverse nature of one of the iterators. So, without knowing about the container itself or at least its size, there is no possibility to get from one end of the container to the other, and since iterators don't have that knowledge, there is no possibility to get from `rend()` to `end()`, from `end()` to `begin()` etc. without additional information.

The minimum needed information is the size of the "gap" between the two points. With that and the normal conversion between reverse and non-reverse iterators it is an easy task:

```
auto rend = v.rend();
auto begin = rend.base();
assert(begin == v.begin());
auto end = begin + v.size();  //the size is the key!
assert(end == v.end());
```

But, since you can not obtain the size from the `reverse_iterator` but only from the container itself, you can easily ask it for `end()` in the first place.

Answer (score -2):

Expression

```
myvec.rend().base()
```

is equivalent to

```
myvec.begin()
```

Here is a demonstrative example

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main() 
{
    std::vector<int> v = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };

    std::vector<int>::iterator it = v.rend().base();

    std::cout << *it << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

The output is

```
1
```

Another demonstrative program that shows the relation between `std::vector<int>::iterator` and `std::vector<int>::reverse_iterator` (instead of templetae argument `int` you may use any type `T`>

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main() 
{
    std::vector<int> v = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };

    if ( v.begin() == v.rend().base() )
    {
        std::cout << "v.begin() == v.rend().base()" << std::endl;
    }

    if ( v.end() == v.rbegin().base() )
    {
        std::cout << "v.end() == v.rbegin().base()" << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The output is

```
v.begin() == v.rend().base()
v.end() == v.rbegin().base()
```

Comment: This is not an answer to the question. The question is about the realtion between `rend()` and `end()`, not between `rend()` and `begin()`.